# Qt Application switches focus to a different application after using a file open dialog

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dialog, cross-platform

I'm porting one of my Qt apps to Windows after developing on OSX. I didn't have this problem with OSX, but it happens now under Windows 8. When I open and select a file with `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()`, the focus switches to some other app and I have to alt-tab back into mine. How do I make Qt revert to the main app once the file is selected in the dialog instead of doing this?

Comment: Please include the entire line where you call `getOpenFileName`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just forgot to set the `parent` for the `QFileDialog` - you need to pass the pointer to the current window to [getOpenFileName](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName):

```
 QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
                                             "",
                                             tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
```